# Linux kernel source code download

Tags: linux-kernel

after the attack on kernel.org, the site is down, I need to download kernel version 3.0 asap, does anyone knows a mirror site where I can download it from ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Linux is also in Github:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux

Comment: found it, thanks a lot. a more specific link: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Google has a cached page from kernel.org that describes several mirrors:

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:F-zvQL6qk8sJ:www.kernel.org/mirrors/countries/html/US.html+linux+kernel+source+mirrors&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca

Answer (score 0):

you can find it on this mirror site http://ftp.yandex.ru/kernel.org/linux/kernel/v3.0/testing/v3.0/